Execution failed for task ':printing:verifyReleaseResources' in Flutter: resource android:attr/lStar not found error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':printing:verifyReleaseResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /Users/mac/Documents/FlutterDev/flutter_projects/ledgerBook/build/printing/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

dependencies:
printing: 5.13.2
flutter clean
flutter build apk --release
